# new column of d_score

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I want to create a new column of d_score in the data frame.  This is a small example of my data with the relevant columns:

```
    trial_id    RT  image_type  sentence_type   sent_image
    1       2486.375784   neg           neg       neg.neg
    2       1189.227724   pos           neg       neg.pos
    3       1326.685536   pos           pos       pos.pos
    4       975.075964    pos           neu       neu.pos
    5       918.369028    neg           neg       neg.neg
    6       896.206442    pos           neu       neu.pos
    7      1077.260149    neg           pos       pos.neg
    8      2245.219066    pos           neu       neu.pos
    9      1732.772871    neg           pos       pos.neg
    10      894.978814    pos           neu       neu.pos
    11      1853.728413   neg           neg       neg.neg
    12      1101.88968    pos           pos       pos.pos
    13      2349.069928   neg           neu       neu.neg
    14      1768.511491   neg           pos       pos.neg
```

I created two baseline values that are an average of RT for two values from image_type column (positive and negative images) :

```
    baselineRT.neu.neg<-mean(df.clean$RT[df.clean$sent_image=="neu.neg"])
```

this is baseline for neg_image

```
    baslineRT.neu.pos<-mean(df.clean$RT[df.clean$sent_image=="neu.pos"])
```

this is baseline for pos_image

Now I want to create a new column of the d_score.  The numeric value in each cell will be calculated as follows:  if the image_type==pos  then the `baselineRT.neu.pos` should be subtracted from the RT value. If the image is negative then the `baselineRT.neu.neg` should be subtracted from the RT value. I started writing the script and got stuck because I'm pretty new at R.

I tried two directions:

```
     df$d_score<-ifelse(df$image_type=='neg', 
     df[,9]-baselineRT.neu.neg, df[,9]-
     baselineRT.neu.pos)
```

or

```
     mutate(df, d_score =ifelse...
```

but I don't know how to continue

Can someone direct me?

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please edit your question and add minimal reproducible example as R code containing example data (e. g. created with `dput(your.data.frame)` and show the expected output for this example. This makes it easier for us to answer. THX :-)

Comment: The example must be reproducible for others. Create sample data so we can just run the code you provide, e.g. df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
# load several packages to make it easier for you
library(tidyverse)

# create a sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
    a = rnorm(10)
    , b = 1:10
    , c = 21:30
)

# take the dataframe (df)...
df %>% # ...and then
    mutate(d = if_else(a <= 0, b + c, b - c))

# calculate b+c if a <= 0 and otherwise b-c
```